# How to create a grid using pygame

Tags: python, pygame, grid

I have created a surface but i am not sure how to make a grid because i have tried using the rectangle function but do not fully understand the parameter.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

Background = pygame.display.set_mode((900,900))


pygame.draw.rect(Background,green,_____)
```

I don't understand how i am suppose to use this to create grid because even if i can get the code to work, I don't know how to position the item and there must be a more efficient way to create a grid rather then manually creating and positioning each box.

Comment: You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029253/how-to-add-afterimages-in-pygame/57036850#57036850

Comment: Here's another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56984542/is-there-an-effiecient-way-of-making-a-function-to-drag-and-drop-multiple-pngs/56987691#56987691

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way - you should use loops to create grids. The third argument for the `pygame.draw.rect` is a rectangle, meaning four values that are packed together (say in a tuple): start x, start y, width and height - but lines are more useful for grids usually. This will draw a simple grid, with spaces of 50 pixels, and then keep the display active with a loop:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

Background = pygame.display.set_mode((900 ,900))

for i in range(0, 900, 50):
    pygame.draw.line(Background, (255, 255, 255), (0, i), (900, i))
    pygame.draw.line(Background, (255, 255, 255), (i, 0), (i, 900))
pygame.display.update()

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pass
```

Really the only slightly complex part here is the lines. The first to arguments are the same as they are for rectangles. The last two arguments are a starting point for the line and an ending point, and optionally you could add width, which I didn't - in which case the get the default width of 1 pixel.